# Не подключаются файлы JS

Tags: javascript

http://new.norbi-tv.ru/ Не запускаются скрипты. гугл выводит следующие ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?php
 require_once ('norbi_customize.php');
 require_once ('BootstrapNavMenuWalker.php');

/*registration style*/
 wp_register_style(
  'style',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
 wp_register_style(
  'bootstrap_css',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 wp_register_style(
  'bootstrap_theme_css',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'font_awesome_css',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'header',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'index',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/index.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'page',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/page.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'footer',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/footer.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'sidebar',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/sidebar.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'category',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/category.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  '404',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/404.css');
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'animate',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css');
    wp_enqueue_style(
  'fancybox_css',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.fancybox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style(
  'MetroJs',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/MetroJs.css');
    wp_enqueue_style(
  'MetroJs_min',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/MetroJs.min.css');

 
/*style turn to loading*/
 wp_enqueue_style('style');
 wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css');
 wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_theme_css');
 wp_enqueue_style('font_awesome_css');
 wp_enqueue_style('header');
 wp_enqueue_style('index');
 wp_enqueue_style('page');
 wp_enqueue_style('footer');
 wp_enqueue_style('sidebar');
 wp_enqueue_style('category');
 wp_enqueue_style('404');
 wp_enqueue_style('animate');
        wp_enqueue_style('fancybox_css');
 wp_enqueue_style('MetroJs');
 wp_enqueue_style('MetroJs_min');


/*registration script*/
 wp_register_script(
  'jQuery',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'bootstrap_js',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'jquery.sticky',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.sticky.js');
       wp_register_script(
  'fancybox_js',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'script',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'jquery.maskedinput',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.maskedinput.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'jquery.maskedinput.min',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'phone',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/phone.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'ajax_check_street',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/module_check_street/js/ajax_check_street.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'MetroJs',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/MetroJs.js');
 wp_register_script(
  'MetroJs_min',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/MetroJs.min.js');


 /*script turn to loading*/
  wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js'); 
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery.sticky');
        wp_enqueue_script('fancybox_js');
  wp_enqueue_script('script');
 wp_enqueue_script('ajax_check_street');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery.maskedinput');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery.maskedinput.min');
 wp_enqueue_script('phone');
 wp_enqueue_script('MetroJs');
 wp_enqueue_script('MetroJs_min');




/*registration menu*/
 register_nav_menu('header_menu','Header Menu');

/*form-search html5*/
 add_theme_support('html5', array('search-form'));
/*number print words in index*/
function do_excerpt($string, $word_limit) {
    $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
    if (count($words) > $word_limit)
        array_pop($words);
    echo implode(' ', $words).' ...';
}
/*replacement separator title*/
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', function(){ return ' | '; } );
?>
```

Comment: Смотри внимательнее на пути, других причин в принципе быть не может.

Comment: @Oma Так файлы ксс подключаются, а в соседней папке js не работает